# Await function does not contain full data from Promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await, promise

I don't understand why this isn't working as I expect it to.

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const pages = await generateURLs();
    console.log(pages);
    console.log(await generateURLs());
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return;
  }
})();
```

`console.log(await generateURLS())` returns the full array that is returned from the function. But `const pages = await generateURLs()` only contains the first item from the array. Please help me understand why?

The function `generateURLs()` returns a promise as shown below.

```
function generateURLs() {
  let urls = [];
  const directories = [
    {
      name: 'components',
      path: 'build/components',
    },
    {
      name: 'patterns',
      path: 'build/patterns',
    },
    {
      name: 'styles',
      path: 'build/styles',
    },
  ];

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (const directory of directories) {
      fs.readdir(directory.path, (err, folders) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          for (const folder of folders) {
            glob(`${directory.path}/${folder}/**/*.html`, { ignore: `${directory.path}/${folder}/index.html` }, (er, files) => {
              if (er) {
                console.log('Problem getting files paths: ' + er);
              } else {
                for (const file of files) {
                  urls.push(file);
                  resolve(urls);
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You need to be using Promise.all() with an array of promises if you want to do a loop.

Comment: @Klaider not sure how when you have two loops and they have is asynchronous calls

Comment: Hi thanks, would you be able to show me how this could be done?

Comment: `fs/promises` exposes [readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options) with a promise-based api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.readDir` is asynchronous.

This means that resolving  the promise returned from `generateURLs` in the first iteration of the innermost `for (const file of files)` loop allows the caller access to the `urls` array when it only contains entries pushed for the first directory of the `for( directory of directories)` loop.

Rather than resolving in the innermost loop, the promise returned by `generateURLs` should be resolved after all the operations performed inside the outmost `for (const directory of directories)` loop have been completed and `urls` array contains all entries to be passed to the caller.

However, some of these operations are themselves asynchronous, i.e. both `fs.readdir` and `glob` return asynchronous results via callback functions.

Solutions might be to use `fs.readirSync` and `glob.sync` to perform the operations synchronously, or build a nest of callback functions, or convert the operations to return promises and either proceed with creating an array of promises and wait for them to be resolved using `Promise.all`, or use `await` operators inside an `async` function.

Of these, using `await` is probably the simplest to code but initiates file system requests in sequence rather than in parallel (which might be preferred anyway).

The following example is an outline of how `generateURLs` could be converted into an `async` function that returns a promise for the `urls` array. Any errors thrown by `await` below will simply reject the promise returned by `generateURLs`.  I've shown it as a CommonJS module but mainly to encapsulate some of the support code:

```
"use strict"; // generateURLs as a module

const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

// Use promisify to convert callback methods to promise returning
const glob = util.promisify( require("glob"));
const readdir = util.promisify(fs.readdir)

async function generateURLs() {
  let urls = [];
  const directories = [
    {
      name: 'components',
      path: 'build/components',
    },
    {
      name: 'patterns',
      path: 'build/patterns',
    },
    {
      name: 'styles',
      path: 'build/styles',
    },
  ];

  for (const directory of directories) {
    const folders= await readdir(directory.path);
    for (const folder of folders) {
       const files = await glob(`${directory.path}/${folder}/**/*.html`, { ignore: `${directory.path}/${folder}/index.html` });
       for (const file of files) {
         urls.push(file);
       }
    }
  }
  return urls;
}
module.exports = generateURLs;
```

I have not attempted to explain exactly why the posted code produces the bad output it does. In my experience, making sure the returned promise is resolved after `urls` is fully populated is more productive than working out why resolving it too early produces the results it does.

Comment: Good approach. I use `Promise` so little that I didn't think of this promisify utility.